# Recognition Listener not listen

Tags: android, service, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I created this service to listen in the background, career service, but do not know if the listener listen or not, yet only show in  the Logcat message when the service starts ... I have read others questions in stackoberflow but anything run in my case.

```
public class ServicioVoz extends RecognitionService {

private SpeechRecognizer sr;
private VoiceResultsListener vrl;
public Principal principal;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i("Dins del servei", "Arrancat");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("SimpleVoiceService", "Service stopped");
}

@Override
protected void onCancel(Callback listener) {
    sr.cancel();
}

@Override
protected void onStartListening(Intent recognizerIntent, Callback listener) {
    Log.e("escoltant", "________________________________");
    sr.setRecognitionListener(new VoiceResultsListener(listener));
    sr.startListening(recognizerIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onStopListening(Callback listener) {
    sr.stopListening();
    Log.e("Atura d'escoltar", "________________________________");
}

/* INICIALIZAMOS UNA NUEVA CLASE*/
private class VoiceResultsListener implements RecognitionListener {

    private Callback UserListener;

    public VoiceResultsListener(Callback userSpecifiedListener) {
        UserListener = userSpecifiedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        try {
            UserListener.beginningOfSpeech();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ERROR", "No comença ha escoltar");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            UserListener.bufferReceived(buffer);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        try {
            UserListener.endOfSpeech();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {
        try {
            UserListener.error(error);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
        try {
            UserListener.partialResults(partialResults);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        try {
            UserListener.readyForSpeech(params);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        Log.e("resultats", "nose que possar");
        try {
            UserListener.results(results);
            ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            String text = "";
            for (String result : matches)
                text += result + "\n";

            Log.e("", text);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        try {
            UserListener.rmsChanged(rmsdB);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

***Convert voice to text with your custom UI using below class..***

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SRActivity extends Activity implements RecognitionListener {

    Context context;
    private SpeechRecognizer speech;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String tag = getPackageName().toString();
    TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sr);
        context = SRActivity.this;
        Button speakBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        speakBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                speech = SpeechRecognizer
                        .createSpeechRecognizer(SRActivity.this);
                speech.setRecognitionListener(SRActivity.this);

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,
                        "en");
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                        SRActivity.this.getPackageName());

                // workin fine
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);

                // use judiciously! Additionally, depending on the recognizer
                // implementation, these values may have no effect.
                intent.putExtra(
                        RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS,
                        3000L);

                // use judiciously! Additionally, depending on the recognizer
                // implementation, these values may have no effect.
                intent.putExtra(
                        RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS,
                        5000L);

                speech.startListening(intent);
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                progressDialog.show();
                progressDialog.setMessage("My Custom Dialog here");
            }
        });

        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Stop Listning
                speech.stopListening();

            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.speech.RecognitionListener#onBeginningOfSpeech()
     */
    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.e(tag, "onBeginningOfSpeech");

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.speech.RecognitionListener#onBufferReceived(byte[])
     */
    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] arg0) {
        // Log.e(tag, "onBufferReceived");
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.speech.RecognitionListener#onEndOfSpeech()
     */
    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        Log.e(tag, "onEndOfSpeech");

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.speech.RecognitionListener#onError(int)
     */
    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {

        String mError = "";
        switch (error) {
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
            mError = " network timeout";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
            mError = " network";
            return;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
            mError = " audio";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
            mError = " server";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
            mError = " client";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
            mError = " speech time out";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
            mError = " no match";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
            mError = " recogniser busy";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
            mError = " insufficient permissions";
            break;

        }
        textView.setText(mError);
        Log.e(tag, "onError " + mError);

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.speech.RecognitionListener#onEvent(int, android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
        Log.e(tag, "onEvent");

    }

    /*
     *
     */
    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
        Log.e(tag, "onPartialResults");

    }

    /*
     * Called when the endpointer is ready for the user to start speaking.
     */
    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        Log.e(tag, "onReadyForSpeech");
    }

    /*
     * Called when recognition results are ready.
     */
    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        Log.e(tag, "onResults");
        ArrayList<String> matches = results
                .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        textView.setText("" + matches.get(0));
        Log.e(tag, "onResults" + matches.toString());

    }

    /*
     * The sound level in the audio stream has changed. There is no guarantee
     * that this method will be called.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        // Log.e(tag, "onRmsChanged");
    }

}
```

***Layout if you need...***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Speak Results" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="3 Sec delay Silence before auto stop, 5 Sec Minimum length of recording  " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="Speak" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="93dp"
        android:text="Stop Speak" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Courtesy  :** https://github.com/Mohammed-khurram-Ahmed/SpeechToTextWithoutDefaultUI

Comment: Thanks, but I want in a service.